# Angular Universal [Node] use Express variables

Tags: angular, angular-universal

I'm trying to build an Angular 2 universal app which needs to call an API

The API currently uses the request's header to determine if it's one of our customer base (we're an ISP).

This works absolutely fine client side, however for the Node side of the application it's always going to be the server's IP.

So I was wondering if there's a way for the Angular Universal App (when running as node) to query Express (?) to pull this out of the request headers?

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I've got this 'working' by adding an IP variable in the environment.ts file, then editing my server.js

```
function ngApp(req: any, res: any) {
    environment.ip = req.headers['x-forwarded-for'] || req.connection.remoteAddress;
    res.render('index', {
        req,
        res,
        ngModule: AppModule,
        preboot: false,
        baseUrl: '/',
        requestUrl: req.originalUrl,
        originUrl: req.hostname
    });
}
```

Now it's accessible by my app, but on a scale of 1 - 10, how dirty would you say this is? cos it feels pretty horrendous.